# Parse remote DOM in JS

Tags: javascript, node.js, dom

I want to get the DOM of a remote web site and be able to parse it, i.e. ideally to convert parsed result into a DOM nodes and effectively grab desired elements from it and later process them. Namely I would like to slice certain elements from retrieved DOM and store them in array for further operations. Is it actually achievable?
So far I've come with this:

```
import request from 'request';

export default function getBody(url, callback) {
  request(url, (err, res, body) => {
    callback(body);
  });
}
```

And in the routes folder:

```
import express from 'express';
import getBody from '../server';

const router = express.Router();

const url = 'http://www.google.com';
let result = {};

getBody(url, response => {
  result = response;
});

router.get('/', (req, res, next) => {
  res.render('index', { title: 'Express', data: result });
});

export default router;
```

This code gets the DOM of the remote page into my view, but the result comes back as a giant string and it will be a nightmare to handle it. I've tried to use [browser-request](https://github.com/iriscouch/browser-request) library to handle it from the front-end, but I couldn't get the headers work and it would always return an error `No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:3000' is therefore not allowed access.`

What is the best course of action in order to get remote DOM and parse it in the way described above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're familiar with jQuery you can use [cheerio](http://cheeriojs.github.io/cheerio/) to go through the DOM.

```
import request from 'request';
import cheerio from 'cheerio';

export default function getBody(url, callback) {
  request(url, (err, res, body) => {
    $ = cheerio.load(body);
    $('h2') // finds all of the `h2` tags within the `body` object.
  });
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, just what I needed.